# View not showing the same result as the query

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I have a View in SQL Server and its showing a different result from a simple query.
[image: Code from the View]

and this is the exactly same query, but without creating a view
[image: Code from the Query]

I've tried to create new View, I tried to use sp_RefreshView, I changed some code from the Create View, i dont know what it can be.
The right result is from the query, not from the View.

Why it is different?

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/****** Object:  View [QEHS].[V_FactMonitorings25261gui]    Script Date: 11/07/2019 16:24:53 ******/
CREATE view 
    [QEHS].[V_FactMonitorings25261gui]
as 

    with
    Plants as 
    (
        select distinct 
            [plant-id] 
        from 
            [QEHS].[Fact-Monitorings-H&S]           
    ) , 
    MIDs as 
    (
        select mid 
        from 
        (
            values
                ( 'MON.02.25 Total number of LTA free days (calendar days)')
                ,( 'MON.02.26 Total number of TRI free days (calendar days)') 
        ) as x(mid) 
    ), 
    PlantList 
    AS
    (
        select 
            a.date, 
            b.[plant-id], 
            c.mid
        from 
            QEHS.Calendar_Gen A 
            cross join 
            plants b    
            cross join mids c
        where 
            year(a.date) >= 2011
    ), 
    help1 as 
    (
        SELECT 
            p.date, 
            p.[plant-id],
            p.mid, 
            t.value,
            (
            case 
                when (year(p.date) = year(getdate()) and month(p.date) = month(getdate())) then 
                    day(getdate()) 
                else 
                    iif(t.value is not null, 0, day(eomonth(p.date)))           
                end 

            ) Days, 
            cast(isnull(cast(t.value as bit),0) as integer) reset 
        FROM 
            PLANTLIST p 
            left join 
            [QEHS].[Fact-Monitorings-H&S] T
            on
            (
                 p.date = t.date and 
                 p.[plant-id] = t.[plant-id] and 
                 p.mid = t.[monitoring-id] 
            )           
    ), 
    help2 as 
    (
        select 
            date, 
            [plant-id], 
            mid, 
            value, 
            days, 
            reset,
            formatmessage('%s%s%d', [plant-id], mid,sum(reset) over 
                ( 
                    partition by  [plant-id], mid 
                    order by  date, [plant-id], mid
                )
            ) grp
        from
            help1 
        where 
            year(date) >= (select year(min(date)) from [QEHS].[Fact-Monitorings-H&S])       
    ),
    help3 as 
    (
        select 
            date, 
            [plant-id], 
            mid, 
            value, 
            days, 
            first_value(value) over (partition by grp order by date, [plant-id], mid) fullvalue
        from 
            help2 
    ) 
    -- 
    select 
        date, 
        [plant-id], 
        mid, 
        isnull(a.Value, 
            fullvalue +sum(days) over 
            (
                 partition by [plant-id], mid, fullvalue 
                 order by  mid, date, [plant-id]
                 rows between unbounded preceding and current row
            ) 
        ) total
    from 
        help3 a

GO
```

Its showing a different results in the view, if I get the code from the view and simple make a query I get the right result.

Comment: We really need a way to replicate this. If the SQL in your View, and the SQL you are running truly *are* the same, they will return the same results.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, its the same SQL, its in the same database, maybe I will try to put all the Schemas creating another View, but its the same

Comment: Just for kicks, put fully qualified tables names.  i.e. My_Db.schema.table_name.  Try it that way and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @RobertSievers Hi Robert, I tried that, unfortonately still the same